# Changing CSS of one element from a list made in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have javascript that creates a nav bar - unordered list with several regular lists inside. I wanted to use the last list element in the nav bar to toggle the visibility (opacity) of another element. So I've been using this so far:

```css
li:last-child:hover ~ #test{
    opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

The element I want to toggle is a div marked with the id Test. In structure, my code goes:

```
<body onload="javascript that makes the menu...">
    <div id="menu" //this houses the li elements that are created by the javascript></div>
    <div id="test">
```

But for some reason, my code to alter the #test element doesn't have any effect. However, if I try to change the style of the last list element itself, it works fine.

How can I fix this CSS so that it actually affects the #test element?

Comment: I'm confused. If you're trying to avoid using Javascript/jQuery, why did you put them in the tags and title?

Comment: There's no `li` element in your HTML, so it won't match that selector.

Comment: I would guess you are actually naming multiple elements with the id `#test` which is invalid and will only affect the first one found in the DOM.

Comment: @Barmar Typo on the jQuery thing, my bad. And there is an li element in my HTML - it's in the menu. I should specify that better. It goes as follows:

Comment: Edit the question, don't try to put code in a comment

Comment: The general sibling selector `~` only works downstream, i.e. siblings that follow the element that matches the selector. If `#test` occurs upstream (even in the same parent), it will not work. It seems like you are trying to transverse up one level (to the parent `#menu`) and select its sibling `#test`. This is unachievable using CSS.

Comment: @Deryck I think he only has one `#test`, he just wants the selector to only match when he's hovering over the last list element.

Comment: @Deryck Exactly, I'm trying to alter the #test element only when hovering over the last list element. The div with the id test is not inside the div containing the id menu.

Comment: oh you cant do that lol your div is outside of the scope of your `li` set.  wasnt reading your code all the way but yeah @Terry has it exactly.

Comment: @Terry So then the solution would be to place test inside menu? Or, is it safer to use some form of Javascript?

Comment: it'd be awesome if you'd put this in a jsfiddle. it'd help get your question answered correctly.

Comment: @Todd Putting it on jsfiddle seems to produce a different output than what I could get normally, different enough to the point where it doesn't help here (the list elements aren't visible). I'm just using code from an already publicly available source. Am I allowed to directly link to it?

Comment: it's not a great idea, no. I typically don't follow external links. It sounds like you're simply missing some list element css rules. I'd copy the relevant html, css, and js into a fiddle.

Comment: alright, here's a fiddle: though for some reason, some javascript shows up in the output as plain text. I couldn't get it to work by separating the scripts from the stylesheets, apologies for that. It is labeled fairly clearly though.
also, this is taken right off of twily if anybody is inclined to see the original source.

anyways, the area labeled notes should make the green area disappear on hover. as of now, I cant get it to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/52apupu3/3/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript if you want the hover event on an element to affect another element that is not a child of the original.

**CSS**

```
.transparent{
opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

Edit: You need to make sure to either include the jQuery *after*  the **HTML**, or wrap it in a `ready` block.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li:last-child').hover(function () {
        $('#test').addClass('transparent'); //mouseover
    }, function () {
        $('#test').removeClass('transparent'); //mouseout
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but ended up getting the following error message when inspecting:

TypeError: $(...) is null test.html:191:4 (same line as the start of the jQuery).

Could this be the result of some interaction between the different parts of my Javascript?

Comment: @javascriptwillbetheendofme see edit, you probably have the script being run before the HTML is added to the dom

Comment: tried that as well, didn't work. or maybe I'm thinking of something completely different than what you just said. here's a jsfiddle of it, maybe that will help?

http://jsfiddle.net/52apupu3/4/